# While passing internal of sharepoint field is not working

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am reading the sharepoint document library's file properties using column display name its working fine using the below code:

```
SPFile spFile=Web.GetFile(Context.Request.Url.ToString());
string spDocumentType=string.Empty;
if (Convert.ToString(spFile.Properties["Document Type"]) == "INV") 
 {
 spDocumentType = Convert.ToString(spFile.Properties["Document Type"]);
}
```

but while I am passing the internal name of "Document Type" field like below its not working or not reading the field value, how can I read the field value passing the internal name?

```
SPFile spFile=Web.GetFile(Context.Request.Url.ToString());
string spDocumentType=string.Empty;
if (Convert.ToString(spFile.Properties["Document_x0020_Type"]) == "INV") 
 {
 spDocumentType = Convert.ToString(spFile.Properties["Document_x0020_Type"]);
}
```

Comment: And why do you want to use its internal name?

Comment: Display may be change later if required, in this case code will not work.

Comment: Are you sure that this column's internal name is "Document_x0020_Type"? Maybe it is just "DocumentType"? Also try to use spFile.Item["Document_x0020_Type"].

Comment: The internal field name is correct and it works with spFile.Item. Thanks for your answer.